# Issue Placeholder Auto Suggestions

Tags: html, input, autocomplete

Then add email word in input placeholder chrome shows suggestions.
I'm using `autocomplete="off" / autocomplete="nope" / autocomplete="false" / autocomplete="some random string"` with input tag and javascript. but chrome never ever disable suggestions.

Comment: Try autocomplete='off'

Comment: `autocomplete='off'` is the correct way, but some versions of Chrome ignore it. I found that putting a dummy value, like `autocomplete='blah'`, works. So I don't know why `autocomplete='nope'` didn't work...

Comment: we found a solution for this issue. `<input id="clients_temp" type="text" class="form-control" data-field="#clients" placeholder="Start typing the client name / Em&zwnj;ail / ESIID ..." autocomplete="off">` the email keyword in placeholder create auto suggestions for users. we have add a hidden html code. like this `Em&zwnj;ail`.

Comment: Ali Sufyan you should add your previous comment as an answer so we can vote on it, it worked like a charm for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we found a solution for this issue. `<input id="clients_temp" type="text" class="form-control" data-field="#clients" placeholder="Start typing the client name / Em&zwnj;ail / ESIID ..." autocomplete="off">` the email keyword in placeholder create auto suggestions for users. we have add a hidden html code. like this `&zwnj;`

E`&zwnj;`mail = Email

try new things stop for browser suggestions.

```
$(document).on('keypress click focus blur','input',function(e){
    var isChrome = /Chrome/.test(navigator.userAgent) && /Google Inc/.test(navigator.vendor);
    ele.autocomplete = isChrome ? 'disabled' :  'off';
});
```